# what type of redirect to a connection page should I use?

Tags: http, redirect, seo

What type of redirect should I be using to redirect a user to a connection page if he needs to be authenticated before using one service of my website ?

Just to be sure using the right numbers for the crawler's to witness what a good student I am !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Available redirection statuses:

[`301 Moved Permanently`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.4.2)

> The 301 (Moved Permanently) status code indicates that the target
> resource has been assigned a new permanent URI.

[`302 Found`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.4.3)

> The 302 (Found) status code indicates that the target resource resides
> temporarily under a different URI.

[`303 See Other`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.4.4)

> The 303 (See Other) status code indicates that the server is
> redirecting the user agent to a different resource.

[`304 Not Modified`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7232#section-4.1)

> There is no need for the server to transfer a representation of the
> target resource because the request indicates that the client already
> has a valid representation.

[`307 Temporary Redirect`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.4.7)

> This status code is similar to 302 (Found), except that it does not
> allow changing the request method from POST to GET.

[`308 Permanent Redirect`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7238#section-3)

> This status code is similar to 301 (Moved Permanently), except that it
> does not allow changing the request method from POST to GET.

*Statuses [`305 Use Proxy`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.4.5) and [`306 (Unused)`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.4.6) are respectively deprecated and no longer used.*

So by default, I would choose the [`303 See Other`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.4.4), since it's the one that suits your needs the best.

Comment: Yes `303 See other` seems to be the appropriate one. Can you please include the link of where you found that list ?

Comment: I just read them from the [IETF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Engineering_Task_Force)'s [RFC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Request_for_Comments)s. RFC 7231 has a table listing all the covered statuses [section 6.1](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.1) (308 is missing but linked in 307's description).

Answer (score 0):

**You should not redirect a user if he need to be logged in to view an URL.**

This URL should shoot a 401 status with a form to let your user log in directly. And then return him the content with an HTTP 200 on the same URL.

Some information on 401 from [HTTP specifications](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.2):

> 401 Unauthorized
>
> The request requires user authentication. The
> response MUST include a WWW-Authenticate header field (section 14.47)
> containing a challenge applicable to the requested resource. The
> client MAY repeat the request with a suitable Authorization header
> field (section 14.8). If the request already included Authorization
> credentials, then the 401 response indicates that authorization has
> been refused for those credentials. If the 401 response contains the
> same challenge as the prior response, and the user agent has already
> attempted authentication at least once, then the user SHOULD be
> presented the entity that was given in the response, since that entity
> might include relevant diagnostic information. HTTP access
> authentication is explained in "HTTP Authentication: Basic and Digest
> Access Authentication" [43].